# How do I notify the Vitest Discord server admins that it isn't working?

Tags: discord, vitest

I am brand new to Vitest and have some questions that I don't see addressed in the manual or in the videos I've found. I'm trying to get into the Discord server for Vitest to ask those questions but the process stalls and I can't figure out how to make it move forward.

I clicked on the Discord icon in the manual, waited a long time for it to do various updates, and then got a dialog that tells you about the change to notifications. I read the first pane with the toggle set to "before", then read it again with the toggle set to "after", then it let me advance to the second page where I can choose which of my Discord servers to move to the right-hand column. I can click on one, both, or neither and the selected server (if any) is moved to the right-hand column. No matter what I do though, I can't get past that point. The "Continue" buttons are grayed out and clicking on the third option is just ignored.

I need to get past that point so that I can finally ask my Vitest questions but I can't figure out how to get past this dialog.

Can anyone tell me how to notify the admins for this Discord server? I know very little about Discord so I don't know how to contact the admin for a given server.

Once I get into the Discord server, I can finally ask the questions that are holding me up on my current project.

Comment: The problem seems to have resolved on its own. Either the admins saw the problem themselves and fixed it or someone else figured out how to notify them. Should I delete this question since no one actually answered it and the issue has resolved itself?